# Keras 3D target prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I need a model to output regression targets of shape `(3,2)`, where `3` is number of events, and each event has `X and Y` coordinates. The input data can span 1 or more time steps. Here is an examples of my model for the case when input has one time step.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size + 1, embedding, input_length=1))
model.add(LSTM(hidden, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(RepeatVector(3))
model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=True))
```

The model compiles and runs, however it produces the same value for `X, Y` across 3 events. I think this is because of `RepeatVector` layer. How else can I make sure that my output is `(None, 3, 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a hint: if one "sentence" is supposed to generate the 3 events, I think you should not use `input_length=1`, but `input_length=lengthOfTheSentences`.

It's not an advantage to have an `LSTM` layer that processes a sequence of length 1.

You're right to say that the `RepeatVector` is causing identical results 3 times.

Now, depending on "how is your model supposed to detect those events", a different approach may be better.

- Are these sentences "a sequence where the events may be found 'along'"?
- Are these sentences "an idea that determines the events statically"?

Following the second approach, I'd say you could use the first LSTM like this:

```
LSTM(hidden, return_sequence=False)
```

Where hidden must be 6. (You may use more hidden layers whith `return_sequences=True`, but it's important that the last has the amount of outputs compatible with 6).

Then you reshape the result in the form of your events:

```
Reshape((3,2))
```

Example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size + 1, embedding, input_length=sentenceLength))
model.add(LSTM(hidden1, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(hidden2, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(hidden3, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Reshape((3,2)))
```